# how can we clean the Google search URL's list,using by DOM

Tags: php, url, dom

We are working on, one of our project related to Google, in which we need a list of search URLs from Google.com. Please look at our code.

```
include('dom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = "http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtmlfile($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

 foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('href')."<br>";
 }
```

we are getting the list of all the URLs in the Google search results page. see below....

```
/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/users/login&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CB8QqwMoADAA&usg=AFQjCNG2OZyIKUhw3qJpqiEgscmvrCRoYw
/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CCUQqwMoAzAA&usg=AFQjCNFqJTvfXN8zUDwS_1jYs4xt5w0NJA
/url?q=http://careers.stackoverflow.com/&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CCEQqwMoATAA&usg=AFQjCNEt6onx0tAMTtPB0Qzx0mJhnabQ5w
/url?q=http://blog.stackoverflow.com/&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CCcQqwMoBDAA&usg=AFQjCNF674QxjxMjvwaLRXTN5qcjHNPQ9Q
```

we require only the top 10 search results, with no additional parameters which is added Google, like this `http://stackoverflow.com/users/login` cleaned URL

**Edited**
In anther this case, in random cases, sometimes the values have some genuine parameters `http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?checking=ok&tesing=working` , but if we explode the URLs then we can return the right parameter. 
**Edited**

Please help me to make this script better.

Thanks

PPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be as simple as;

```
$url = explode('&sa=','/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/users/login&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CB8QqwMoADAA&usg=AFQjCNG2OZyIKUhw3qJpqiEgscmvrCRoYw');

$cleaned = str_replace('/url?q=','',$p[0]);
print($cleaned);
```

Someone may have a cleaner way of doing it though.

Example:

```
$url = explode('&sa=','/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?checking=ok&tesing=working&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CB8QqwMoADAA&usg=AFQjCNG2OZyIKUhw3qJpqiEgscmvrCRoYw',2);


$cleaned = str_replace('/url?q=','',$url[0]);
print($cleaned);
```

Returns `http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?checking=ok&tesing=working`

Comment: if there will be parameter, then it will not give the right results. in this case :- /url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?testingbypps=genuineparameters&sec_parameter=genuine&sa=U&ei=c_FWUPyTEoHIrQfsiYB4&ved=0CB8QqwMoADAA&usg=AFQjCNG2OZyIKUhw3qJpqiEgscmvrCRoYw     ... then it will not give the right value.

Comment: I have edited it now, the first google param is always &sa= (as far as i know) so this should explode on sa= which means all your genuine params are still there

Answer (score 0):

You can [parse the url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) as you iterate through them like this:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $arrHref=parse_url($tag->getAttribute('href'));
    $yourNewLink=$arrHref['scheme'].$arrHref['host'].$arrHref['path']
    echo $yourNewLink;
}
```

And you can use [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) to get out of the loop when you want:

```
$loopLimit=10;
$curCount=0;
foreach ($tags as $tag) 
{
    $arrHref=parse_url($tag->getAttribute('href'));
    $yourNewLink=$arrHref['scheme'].$arrHref['host'].$arrHref['path']
    echo $yourNewLink;
    $curCount++;
    if($curCount>$LoopLimit)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```